# VertexBuffer3d or ExternalInterface is too slow, how can I optimize?

Tags: vertex-buffer, stage3d

I'm finding some problems uploading a VertexBuffer to the context.

This buffer is ~200000 items long and it takes about +15 seconds, apparently the player has some difficulties uploading it to the context.

Does anyone experienced this? Any solution?

I'm trying to upload the vector in chunks with no success (for now...  )

**Update:**

**Apparently the problem is not the upload, but somewhere else. The data is creating from javascript since is a customized ThreeJS fallback. It works great for small scenes but it slows down exponentially for bigger projects.
Right now I am also investigating ExternalInterface communication speed.**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Uploading with ByteArray is faster, btw it changed quite a lot from player to player. there is a test between ByteArray and Vector http://jacksondunstan.com/articles/1617 try this with your GPU. and also you can do this with async flag or from separate thread

Comment: Hi Sergey, Yeah, the last comments on that post are mine. And yes apparently it's not the vector upload, Im sending the information via externalinterface since it's a JS engine. I'm trying to find where the problem is, but sometimes the execution is stop for 15 sec. I will update my question.